# How to pass datatable object as parameter to object control

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, object, datatable

Is it possible to pass datatable object to another control object as parameter as following :

```
protected void DropDownlist2(string model)
{
     queryString = "Select modelcar from useritem where typecar=@model";

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, useritemConnectionString1);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", model);

     useritemConnectionString1.Open();

     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     ad.Fill(dt);

     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
         DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
         DropDownList2.DataBind();
     }

     useritemConnectionString1.Close();
     Button1(dt);
 }

 private void Button1_Click(DataTable dt)
 {   
     SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     if(dr.HasRows)
     { 
         while (dr.Read()) 
         { 
              System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgControl = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
              HtmlGenericControl paraContainer = new HtmlGenericControl("p");
paraContainer.Controls.Add(imgControl);
              PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(paraContainer);

              //Get Image Information
              imgControl.ImageUrl = dr["Image"].ToString();
          } 
    } 
    else  
        dr.Close();
}
```

For some reason I get this error

> button1_Click(System.data.datatable)is inacccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Even if you would make it `protected` you cannot pass the `DataTable` to the click-event handler since it's signature is different(`Object sender, Eventargs e)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `Button1_Click` method `protected`.

Check, is `Button1` method called from `DropDownlist2` the same as `Button1_Click`?

**Update**

In your dropdownlist selection event handler you should store your `DataTable` object in some field or property of your form. In event handler which corresponds to the your button click you should operate with this field.

Comment: So what should i do then to pass a datatable with all its selected data from the droplist to the button ?

Comment: What do you think a button will do with a DataTable. You can't mean that you expect the button to process the data. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: well what i'm trying to accomplish here is to pass the datatable with the filled data to the button as parameter and then read the datatable with the DataTableReader i updated this line i used DataTableReader reader = dt.CreateDataReader(); instead of SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader(); and try to create image controls passing the filed of url to the imageurl property

Comment: Please anyone help me out with this i need it very much

Comment: Do you want to create image controls based on datatable selected in droplist, when button will be pressed?

Comment: so what you mean here is that i will need static field with public scope to pass the datatable from the Dropdownlist to the button event handler, well i will try that , thank you very much